# Raspberry Pi, serial console, minicom, and gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, raspberry-pi, size, minicom

I'm trying to access my raspberry pi via its serial console on the gpio pins. It's working fine through a USB-3.3v serial dongle. However, there's a problem with long lines and long screens not displaying correctly. I'm running minicom in a gnome-terminal which is not set to 24x80 columns (and gnome-terminal's Terminal/1 (24x80) option) doesn't help.

It's as if minicom completely ignores the sigwinch it must be getting, and/or has no way to send that over the serial line to change the terminal type.

Comment: Not a valid/answer or solution, but I find putty works quite well as a serial terminal in linux.

Comment: Sure, but it's still stuck in GTK+ 1.x.

Comment: There are [other minicom alternatives](http://ec2-54-246-66-171.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/) possibly worth trying (the thread mentions `cu`, `screen`, `seyon`, `conserver` and `kermit`)

Comment: I did some experimenting with xterm vs gnome-terminal, and screen vs minicom. None of them change it. I'm concluding that the problem is on the Debian end, where it's not emitting the correct terminal escape codes.

Comment: May be a solution here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106644/how-to-change-the-width-of-remote-serial-console

Answer (score 2):

You're right, in that `minicom` won't communicate the fact of a window change to the far end.  If you're using a VT100-like emulation, you might be able to do a

```
eval `resize`
```

to generate some control characters that will force the emulator to tell the far end the size of its window.

On Debian-like systems, `resize` is in the `xterm` package.

Comment: At least with zsh and bash it's sufficient to call `resize` as-is. I don't need to eval its output and the shell correctly adjusts the LINES/COLUMNS variables on its own.