# How to change the width of remote serial console?

Tags: terminal, serial-console, minicom

I followed [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20171009071729/http://www.vanemery.net/Linux/Serial/serial-console.html) and now I'm able to connect to serial line. Now I want to change the width of terminal. How can I do this by using screen or minicom or something else?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Serial connections don't have a standard way of setting terminal geometry. The assumed geometry is often 80x23 or 80x24 (terminals with zero to two status lines).

Once you're logged in, you can set your preferred geometry via the shell, using something like

```
stty rows 50 cols 132
```

This will last for the duration of your terminal session, but is not persistent across terminal sessions (e.g. logging out and logging in again).

Unfortunately, resizing the GUI window the terminal emulator runs in won't update this unless some cunning magic is taking place I'm entirely unaware of.

Comment: I also found that despite that `sh` might say thing like `stty: number 0 is not in 1..2147483647 range`, setting to the maximum number would be silently ignored. But e.g. 500 works.

Comment: Extremely useful in Docker environment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For some reason in my docker container, "stty cols 132" does not fix the problem for me however "stty cols 132 && exec bash" does. "tput cols" shows it is updated but it does not fix until I re-run bash.

Comment: Useful when I use Putty connect FreeBSD via Serial connection. Thanks! It would better if it can be set permanently in Putty.

Comment: stty rows 64 cols 270

Answer (score 16):

Instead of launching minicom by typing:

```
minicom
```

type the following instead:

```
TERM=linux minicom
```

Comment: Maybe/maybe **not**: minicom doesn't do anything with that value; you **may** have some application that assumes a particular geometry and sets the terminal size using `stty`.

Comment: I don't understand why, but hell it works exactly the way I want! Thank you sir! I suggest making alias in /etc/.bashrc for anyone that uses it frequently:: **alias='TERM=linux minicom -s**

Comment: @While-E, your alias is incorrect.  Should it be `alias TERM='linux minicom -s'`??

Comment: Above aliases don't work for me.  Instead use `alias minicom='TERM=linux minicom'` (works w/ bash 4.4.12 in GNU/Linux Debian 9.6 stretch).

Comment: This specification of `TERM` works fine for e.g. `vim`, `journalctl` and some other programs, but not for `man`, `gdb` and maybe some more. For these I had to use `stty cols 316 rows 94`.